# Adding 2 session variables in JDBC MySql Connection string

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I need to add 2 session variables in JDBC connection string.

sessionVariables=FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0&sessionVariables=SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0

The second one is overwriting the first variable. Is there any option in JDBC connection to add 2 session variables?

Comment: `A comma or semicolon separated list of name=value pairs to be sent as SET [SESSION] ... to the server when the driver connects.`, see [6.3 Configuration Properties](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html).

Comment: @wchiquito: Thanks. sessionVariables=group_concat_max_len=204800,time_zone='-00:00' this is working good for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can pass this as comma separated like sessionVariables=group_concat_max_len=204800,time_zone='-00:00'